# psql can connect to a unix domain socket, but py-postgresql with the same parameters gets 'Permission denied'

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, unix-socket, py-postgresql

## Problem description:

My system user is `milosz`, which is mapped to the PostgreSQL user `project_great` in `pg_ident.conf`. I am using peer authentication to connect to a PostgreSQL database over a unix domain socket. This connection method works when using `psql`, but fails to work when using `py-postgresql` using the same parameters from within a Python script.

Here I am successfully connecting to the database using `psql`:

```
$ psql -U project_great \
>      -d project_great \
>      -h /var/run/postgresql
psql (9.3.4)
Type "help" for help.

project_great=>
```

Here is `database_test.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import postgresql

params = {
    'user':     'project_great',
    'database': 'project_great',
    'unix':     '/var/run/postgresql',
}

connection = postgresql.open(**params)
```

Here I am attempting to connect to the database by running `./database_test.py`:

```
$ ./database_test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./database_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "./database_test.py", line 13, in main
    connection = postgresql.open(**params)
  File "/home/milosz/devel/project_great/.virtualenv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/postgresql/__init__.py", line 94, in open
    c.connect()
  File "/home/milosz/devel/project_great/.virtualenv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/postgresql/driver/pq3.py", line 2422, in connect
    self._establish()
  File "/home/milosz/devel/project_great/.virtualenv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/postgresql/driver/pq3.py", line 2548, in _establish
    self.typio.raise_client_error(could_not_connect, creator = self, cause = exc)
  File "/home/milosz/devel/project_great/.virtualenv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/postgresql/driver/pq3.py", line 514, in raise_client_error
    raise client_error
postgresql.exceptions.ClientCannotConnectError: could not establish connection to server
  CODE: 08001
  LOCATION: CLIENT
CONNECTION: [failed]
  failures[0]:
    socket'/var/run/postgresql'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/milosz/devel/project_great/.virtualenv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/postgresql/protocol/client3.py", line 136, in connect
        self.socket = self.socket_factory(timeout = timeout)
      File "/home/milosz/devel/project_great/.virtualenv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/postgresql/python/socket.py", line 64, in __call__
        s.connect(self.socket_connect)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    postgresql.exceptions.ConnectionRejectionError: Permission denied
      CODE: 08004
      LOCATION: CLIENT
CONNECTOR: [Unix] pq://project_great@[unix::var:run:postgresql]/project_great
  category: None
DRIVER: postgresql.driver.pq3.Driver
```

Since the parameters to the two connections are ostensibly the same and my permissions on the socket and its containing directory are fairly open, I do not know what the issue is. Using TCP is not a solution; I want to use unix domain sockets. The [py-postgresql documentation](http://python.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/1.0/driver.html#connection-keywords) indicates that connecting using unix domain sockets should work.

## Configuration:

**pg_hba.conf:**

```
# TYPE   DATABASE  USER      ADDRESS             METHOD  OPTION
local    all       all                           peer    map=default
```

**pg_ident.conf:**

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
default         postgres                postgres
default         milosz                  project_great
```

**postgresql.conf:**

```
...
port = 5432
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql'
...
```

Here are the permissions on my socket directory:

```
$ ll /var/run/postgresql/
total 8
drwxrwsr-x  2 postgres postgres 100 May 17 00:20 ./
drwxr-xr-x 31 root     root     900 May 17 00:41 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 postgres postgres   5 May 17 00:20 9.3-main.pid
srwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres   0 May 17 00:20 .s.PGSQL.5432=
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  70 May 17 00:20 .s.PGSQL.5432.lock
```

The PostgreSQL user `project_great` has been granted all privileges on the database `project_great` and both the user and the database exist.

I do not have a `~/.pgpass`.

## Environment:

- Ubuntu 13.10
- Python 3.3
- PostgreSQL 9.3
- py-postgresql 1.1.0

Comment: I'd run both under `strace` and compare.

Comment: Great call. I did so and found my issue almost immediately. Writing up a self-answer right now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Craig Ringer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707988/psql-can-connect-to-a-unix-domain-socket-but-py-postgresql-with-the-same-parame#comment36434194_23707988) suggested to run both programs under `strace` to find out if there is a relevant difference in the system calls. I grepped for `/var/run/postgresql` and found that while `psql` ran `connect` like so:

```
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"}, 110) = 0
```

`./database_test.py` ran `connect` like so:

```
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/postgresql"}, 21) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

wherein lay the issue.

While `psql` expects the *path to the directory* in which the unix domain socket is located, `py-postgresql` expects the *full path* to the socket. Therefore, the fix was to modify `database_test.py` to read like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import postgresql

params = {
    'user':     'project_great',
    'database': 'project_great',
    'unix':     '/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432',
}

connection = postgresql.open(**params)
```

Honestly, I feel silly for not having tried the full path as an earlier debugging step!

Comment: Please report that as a bug to `py-postgresql`. It should be consistent with all the libpq clients like `psql`, `psycopg2`, etc. (BTW, without a good reason I strongly suggest using `psycopg2` not `py-postgresql`).